# Coloring bloxplot in ggplot2 not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, graphing

I am attempting to transparently fill my boxplots with the corresponding color in the legend (red for day 0 and blue for day 7). However, i am only able to transparently fill them both with blue. Here is the code i'm currently running:

```
p <- ggpaired(bactplot, x = "Day", y = "MGBC000574",
          color = "Day", palette = "NPG", id = "Mouse", 
          title = "name_of_species", ylab = "Relative Abundance", xlab = "Day",
          line.color = "grey", line.size = 0.5,
          facet.by = "Treatment", short.panel.labs = FALSE) + theme(legend.position = "bottom", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
          geom_boxplot(aes(fill="Day"), alpha=0.2)
```

And this is the corresponding plot that i get (darkened labels to protect data):
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try without quotes, i.e. do `geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Day))`. For ggpaired you have to pass the column names as quoted strings, while in case of geom_boxplot use unquoted names.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!